# Committing changes in Vagrant

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, virtualbox, commit, vagrantfile

I have an ubuntu machine.

In that I've installed Vagrant and started using vagrant box for ubuntu/xenial64.

I want to install to install git, java, jenkins etc in the ubuntu box

How do I commit the changes I made in the box.

I've tried using `**vagrant package**`. A new box is being created successfully with the changes made. But how do I boot into that box next time with all my softwares installed?

Answer (score 3):

You just simply create a new empty project folder and use the `vagrant init` command with the box name you just created. `vagrant init box_name`. Then `vagrant up`.

Note: Before you can use a packaged box you must add it to vagrant `vagrant box add box_name path/to/package.

Comment: He needs to add the box after the packaging too.

Comment: Is there any way that the changes are saved automatically. I mean if I create a vagrant VM, boot it, install some softwares, and exit the VM, and then vagrant up and vagrant ssh. Will the softwares that I installed last time be present in the VM?